# ros_buildfarm setup issue on repo machine

Tags: ros, buildfarm, ros-noetic

I am setting up ros_buildfarm and got stuck at the "Deploy the forked configuration onto the machines" step in the buildfarm_deployment: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/buildfarm_deployment/blob/master/README.md documentation. On the repo machine, when I run the following command:

./reconfigure.bash repo

I get the following error message:

'''
Could not checkout git://github.com/newrelic/puppet-nrsysmond.git: fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 140.82.112.4]: errno=Connection timed out
'''

This suggests that the puppet-nrsysmond module has not been installed. I also do not see any lines in the script that mention installing or using reprepro.

Checking the Puppetfile in buildfarm_deployment, I see the following:

'''
:git => 'https://github.com/nuclearsandwich/puppet-jenkins',
:ref => '1.7.0-rosbuildfarm3'
mod 'stankevich/python', '1.18.2'
mod 'newrelic-nrsysmond',
:git => "git://github.com/newrelic/puppet-nrsysmond.git"

mod 'saz-timezone', '3.4.0'
'''
puppet-nrsysmond has been archived by the owner on Apr 21, 2020.
I am not sure if the issue with puppet-nrsysmond is preventing the script from installing the necessary tools and manipulating the repo machine. However, the script does not appear to have created or generated anything in the following directories:

/var/repos/ubuntu/testing
/home/jenkins-agent/reprepro_config

After generated the Jenkins jobs using the following command:
generate_all_jobs.py http://192.168.50.10:8081/index.yaml --commit

When I tried to run the Jenkins job "import_upstream", it could not find the files /home/jenkins-agent/reprepro_config/ros_bootstrap.yaml or /home/jenkins-agent/.buildfarm/reprepro-updater.ini and the job fail.

I would appreciate any help.

PS: On the repo machine, I create a user named jenkins-agent and then create a slave node for that user on the master machine to run the job: import_upstream.